# Powershell (?) transforms argument in a very weird way - removes comma from string

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a powershell build step in TeamCity:

```
param ([string] $a)

Write-Host "`$a is '$a'."
```

and in this step I set parameter `$a` as `-a "%TestParam%"` or as `"-a %TestParam%"`, where TestParam has two lines `abra` and `cadabra`.

When I run the build I get the following output:

```
[Step 1/10] PowerShell arguments: -NoProfile, NonInteractive, -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, C:\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell1746295357460795314.ps1, -a, "abra, cadabra"
[Step 1/10] $a is 'abra cadabra'.
```

The only question I have: **What on earth happened to the comma?** Why has it disappeared?

If I do not use quotes at all (`-a %TestParam%`), then TeamCity passes each line as a separate parameter and I see `$a is 'abra'.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447479/45375) explains PowerShell's parsing of `,`-separated tokens as arguments [*his answer has since been deleted, but I hope it will be undeleted*], but that **doesn't apply in the case at hand**, because any **arguments passed to PowerShell's CLI via `-File` are *not* subject to PowerShell's command-line parsing - instead, such arguments are treated as *literals***.

That is, *if* the command line invoked by TeamCity truly were the following:

```
powershell ... -File C:\...ps1 -a "abra, cadabra"
```

then parameter variable `$a` *would* receive value `abra, cadabra`, as expected.

In other words: **What is *actually* being passed in your case must be `abra cadabra`**, not
`abra, cadabra`, so **you need to revise the value of `%TestParam%` to ensure that it actually contains the desired comma**.

---

As for ***why* the *log* of the command invoked suggests that there *is* a `,` present** in what you're passing:

I can only *speculate*, based on your own guess:

> I suspect TeamCity of being a liar, showing lines joined with comma, but passing them without it.

***Perhaps* TeamCity, when *logging* invocation of a command line, naively breaks that command line into tokens by *whitespace only*, without considering *quoting***, and then presents them as a `,`-separated list.

If this is indeed the case, then argument `"abra cadabra"` - without comma - would be logged as
`"abra, cadabra"`, which would explain the confusion.